# Getting this error while initially starting Clima app from Flutter Beginner course. (I copied the whole code and directories to a new project)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**ERROR:C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\clima\android\app\src\main\res\main\AndroidManifest.xml: Resource and asset merger: 'A' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\clima\android\app\src\main\res\main\AndroidManifest.xml: Error: 'A' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 31s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

I copied all the code and the neccessary directories to this newly created project. Since the original was way old and was giving me error about V2embedding and stuff.

Now I don't understand this error that's been bugging me since 2 days, I am learning Flutter Android app making.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, it looks like you copy files in wrong directory:

```
C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\clima\android\app\src\main\res\main\AndroidManifest.xml:
```

Usually Manifest file is in android\app\src\main, not in app\src\main\res\main\

In your case AndroidManifest.xml should be in:

```
C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\clima\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:
```

Check the paths you copy the code.